# In ASP.NET how do you pass eval data to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I just want to pass the row/column bound data to a javascript function.  I've found a ton of samples on here on stackoverflow but I can't get them to work for me.

Here is what I have:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("MECNUM") %>' runat="server"    
     ImageUrl="printer.png" OnClick="Display_OnClick"
     OnClientClick='DoSomething(<%# Eval("MECNUM")%>))' />
```

Again, apologies for the repost of a common question but I've copied/pasted accepted solutions that I could find here and always come up with a parser error.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `"I've copied/pasted accepted solutions"` - That's often not a very good way of writing software.  `"and always come up with a parser error"` - And that error would be... what, exactly?

Comment: is your DoSomething() function globally available i.e can you do add a open and close script tag at the bottom of the generated HTML and just put DoSomething() between them and have it work or do you need to reference the object that contains the function?

Comment: David: Its a parser error - the server tag is not well formed.

Comment: Code: the javascript function is accessible.  I remove the <%# Eval("MECNUM")%> portion and replace it with any string and the function executes fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the overload of Eval that takes a format expression:

```
OnClientClick='<%# Eval(Container.DataItem, "MECNUM", "DoSomething({0})") %>'
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2d76z3ck(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: Thank you, all.  From the link, the version of this code without the Container object worked for me.  Appreciate all the help.